# Como descontar cantidades entre dos colecciones

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Tengo dos colecciones, una de que almacena una orden, con la información básica  y otra que contiene la información general de los productos tal como la descripción, y stock.

Los modelos serian:

El modelo de la orden:

```
const { model, Schema, Types } = require('mongoose');

const ordenSchema = new Schema({
    time : { type : Date, default: Date.now },
    Nro_Orden: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    Tipo: {
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    Estado: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    Lista: [
        {
            Producto: {type: Types.ObjectId}, //Cada producto en esta lista tiene el _id respectivo en la colección de Productos
            Catd: {type: Number, required: true} //Esta es la cantidad que debe restarse en la coleccion de productos
        }
    ]

},{ collection : 'orden' });

module.exports = model('orden', ordenSchema) 

    //EJEMPLO  
    Nro_Orden: '100',
    Tipo: 'Solicitud de market',
    Estado: 'Orden por aprobar',
    Lista:
    [ { _id: 5f433ebc931e4928245f95d3, Catd: 1 },
    { _id: 5f41dd4b19e0f441d820b488, Catd: 1 } ], //Este _id le pertenece al item 00000AAAA
    time: 2020-08-28T05:24:03.167Z,
    __v: 0 }
```

El modelo de los productos:

```
    const { model, Schema } = require('mongoose');

const productosSchema = new Schema({
    Codf: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    Descr: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    Stock: {//De este campo quiero restar la cantidad según la orden
        type: Number,
        required: false
    }
},{ collection : 'productos' });

module.exports = model('productos', productosSchema)  


      //EJEMPLO
    [ { 
    _id: 5f41dd4b19e0f441d820b488,
    Descr: '00000AAAA',
    Codf: '123',
    Stock: 50,
    __v: 0,} ]
```

Mi objetivo es que cuando yo quiero aprobar la orden, se resten las cantidades registradas en la lista de la orden en la colección de productos.

Mi problema es que no se que método usar para unir las dos colecciones y luego restar las cantidades dependiendo de cuantos items haya en la lista de la orden y asi mostrar los cambios de Stock

Comment: Lo que buscas se llama [transacción](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) y es simplemente un sistema que te permite realizar este tipo de operaciones, garantizando la consistencia de los datos. La pregunta es: ¿Tu servidor es de réplica(*replica set*) o es un cluster fragmentado (*sharded cluster*)? Si lo es, ¿qué versión del mismo tienes? Las transacciones son soportadas por MongoDB 4.0 o superior en servidores de réplica, y en clúster fragmentados a partir de la versión 4.2. Dependiendo de lo que tengas, la solución sería crear tu propia lógica de transacciones. Saludos

Comment: Mi servidor es de replica set. Estoy usando la version 4.2 de mongodb. Voy a chequear eso de las transacciones. Gracias por responder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado una solución que se adapta perfectamente al resultado buscado. No sé si con otro método como Transactions de mongodb sea mas rápido, si es así por favor háganmelo saber :D.

En el siguiente código utilizo forEach() para adentrarme a la Orden que es un array. Y posteriormente vuelvo  usar forEach() para contar los elementos de Lista de la orden y para finalizar opero las cantidades modificando los documentos en la colección de Productos.

```
const { orden_id } = req.body;//Almacena el _id de la orden
const orden = await ordenesExtremas.find({ _id: post_id });//Almaceno el documento de la orden

if (orden_origin.length >= 1) { //Verifico que la orden esta siendo almacenada
    orden_origin.forEach(orden => 
        orden.Lista.forEach(async e => { 
            const items_a_procesar = await productosExtremos.findById(e._id) //Almaceno los items que van a ser pasados Al market

            await productosExtremos.findByIdAndUpdate(e._id, { //Ejecuto la operacion
                Stock: items_a_procesar.Stock - e.Catd,
                Market: items_a_procesar.Market - e.Catd,
            })
}
```

Espero logren entender xD. Cualquier duda o sugerencia son bienvenidas :)